# Java Nested Monitors (moving past apparent deadlock)

Tags: java, multithreading, monitor

I'm synchronizing and blocking on the same object.  Each thread calls the testQueue() method in the PuppetShow class which instantiates a distinct object for each thread to block on.  My problem is that once capacity==0, the first thread to encounter that condition calls wait() on its object and then the program hangs and no other thread runs.  The third thread outputs "waaah" per the println statement and then no other lines are executed, despite the fact that I instantiate threads after this one.

How do I move past the lock.wait() line in the testQueue method in the PuppetShow() class?

I want to be able to block on distinct objects and add them to vectors in order to queue groups of threads.  That's why I'm blocking on distinct objects and then adding these to a vector.  To notify the thread I simply notify the element at a position in the vector.

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class PuppetShow {

    private int numSeats = 2;
    private int capacity = numSeats;
    private Vector<Object> attendingPuppetShow = new Vector<Object>();
    public Vector<Object> waitingStudents = new Vector<Object>();

    public void testQueue() {
        Object lock = new Object();
        System.out.println("testQueue begin");
        synchronized(lock) {
            if(testAttending(lock)) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("waaah");
                    lock.wait();
                    System.out.println("ugh");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean testAttending(Object lock) {
        System.out.println("testAttending");
        boolean status;
        if(capacity==0) {   
            waitingStudents.add(lock);
            System.out.println("capacity="+capacity+" ws size="+waitingStudents.size());
            status = true;
        }
        else {
            capacity--;
            attendingPuppetShow.add(lock);
            System.out.println("capacity="+capacity+" aPS size="+attendingPuppetShow.size());
            status = false;
        }       
        return status;
    }

    public synchronized void testRelease() {        
        if(waitingStudents.size() > 0) {
            while(waitingStudents.size() > 0) {
                synchronized(waitingStudents.elementAt(0)) {
                    waitingStudents.elementAt(0).notify();                  
                }
                waitingStudents.removeElementAt(0);
                capacity++;
            }
        }
    }
}

class GreenStudent extends Thread {

    private PuppetShow ps = new PuppetShow();

    public GreenStudent(int id, PuppetShow ps) {
        setName("GreenStudent-" + id);
        this.ps = ps;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        System.out.println(getName()+" queuing for show");
            ps.testQueue();
    }
}

class StaffMember extends Thread {

    private PuppetShow ps = new PuppetShow();

    public StaffMember(int id, PuppetShow ps) {
        setName("StaffMember-" + id);
        this.ps = ps;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ps.testRelease();

    }
}

class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         PuppetShow ps = new PuppetShow();
         GreenStudent gs1 = new GreenStudent(1, ps);
         GreenStudent gs2 = new GreenStudent(2, ps);
         GreenStudent gs3 = new GreenStudent(3, ps);

         StaffMember sm = new StaffMember(1,ps);

         gs1.run();
         gs2.run();
         gs3.run();      
         sm.run();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         gs1.run();
         gs2.run();
         gs3.run();      
         sm.run();
```

Needs to be

```
         gs1.start();
         gs2.start();
         gs3.start();      
         sm.start();
```

In your example, `run` will be invoked by the calling thread (main thread). `start` will launch another thread then eventually call `run`.